# Iterating (with iterators) through vector causes SIGSEGV but works when using in indices - hows that?

Tags: c++, vector, g++, segmentation-fault

I have a vector with pointers to objects that have an `id()` function: `vector<*obj> v`. `id()` returns a integer, unique to the object. At one point in my program I create lets say six objects with id's `{0,1,2,3,4,5}`. Then I shuffle the vector, hence the pointers are in different order: `{1,0,4,2,3,5}`.

When I print the id's (in reversed order) I get a **SIGSEGV** error, depending on how I access the vector:

**by indices: works just fine!**

```
for(int i(v.size()-1); i>=0; --i)
        cout<<v.at(i)->id()<<"  "<<&(v.at(i))<<endl;
```

**by reversed iterators: throws error when accessing the last element: SIGSEGV**

```
for(auto it(v.crbegin()); it!=v.crend(); ++it) //print in reverse order
        cout<<(*it)->id()<<"  "<<&(*it)<<endl;
```

**first going through by indices and then by r-iterators does not cause SIGSEGV but the last id is wrong - but the address is the same:**

```
for(int i(v.size()-1); i>=0; --i)
    cout<<v.at(i)->id()<<"  "<<&(v.at(i))<<endl;
cout<<endl;
for(auto it(v.crbegin()); it!=v.crend(); ++it)
    cout<<(*it)->id()<<"  "<<&(*it)<<endl;
```

**prints:**

```
1  0x1bbd708
0  0x1bbd700
4  0x1bbd6f8
2  0x1bbd6f0
3  0x1bbd6e8
5  0x1bbd6e0

1  0x1bbd708
0  0x1bbd700
4  0x1bbd6f8
2  0x1bbd6f0
3  0x1bbd6e8
0  0x1bbd6e0 ////should be 5!
//program continues!
```

So my question: Why is that, what are probable causes and why is it working with indices and not with iterators? What additional information is needed?

### EDIT

I narrowed it down to the following code which still has the behaviour. I create a Party and let it have 4 Dancers (using new and raw pointers). Then I get a copy of my pointer-vector and let them print their id, whereas the first one fails if I access him with an iterator. Using indices works just fine. (I'm aware of the missing delete.) (Is this a bug in g++; I'm using 4.9.1?)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class Dancer {
public:
    Dancer() : m_id(5+m_count++) { } //add 5 to avoid having a 0
    int id() const  { return m_id; }

private:
    static int m_count;
    const int m_id;
};
int Dancer::m_count=0;


class Party
{
public:
    Party() { }
    void createDancer() { m_dancers.emplace_back(new Dancer()); }
    vector<Dancer*> dancers() { return m_dancers; }

private:
    vector<Dancer*> m_dancers;
};


int main() {
    Party party;
    for(uint i(0); i<4; ++i) //create 4 Dancers
        party.createDancer();

    //Print the id and address of the pointer
    for(unsigned int i(0); i<party.dancers().size(); ++i)  //using indecies
        cout<<party.dancers().at(i)->id()<<"  "<<&(party.dancers().at(i))<<endl;

    cout<<endl;

    for(auto it(party.dancers().cbegin()); it!=party.dancers().cend(); ++it) //using iterators
        cout<<(*it)->id()<<"  "<<&(*it)<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
5  0xb0d0c0
6  0xb0d0c8
7  0xb0d0d0
8  0xb0d0d8

0  0xb0d0c0 //iterator to the first element fails to get the correct id!
6  0xb0d0c8
7  0xb0d0d0
8  0xb0d0d8
```

Comment: There is probably a bug in some other part of your code that is not shown, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, I have that feeling too, but what is the difference between my too loops or their ordder? id() is const and just returns a const int. The objects are not modified...

Comment: @dani Doesn't matter if you have Undefined Behaviour somewhere else. Two pieces of code that under normal circumstances are equivalent may do something entirely different under UB.

Comment: A mcve means minimal code that, all by itself, produces the symptoms.  It can be hard to generate, but worth the effort.  One thing to do is to examine `id()` and see what in that call is going haywire with a debugger.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I shuffle the vector"? How? std::random_shuffle()?  Does the problem still occur if you don't shuffle it

Comment: I use std::shuffle. Yes, it happens also if I don't shuffle up to now I can't find any reason why that happens.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a vector with pointers to objects [...]

No you don't, you have lots and lots of *different* vectors.

`party.dancers()` returns by value, so you get a new object every time you call it.

You can't iterate through that object by using:

```
for(auto it(party.dancers().cbegin()); it!=party.dancers().cend()
```

because the `it` iterator points into a different container to the one you get next time you call `party.dancers()`. This is undefined behaviour.

Even if it worked, it would be incredibly inefficient because you keep creating and destroying new vectors with every call, allocating and deallocating memory needlessly.

(It's also **completely** different to the original code you showed where you showed using a single lvalue vector: `for(auto it(v.crbegin()); it!=v.crend(); ++it)` **This is why you should always show the REAL code not some simplified version that you *think* is equivalent but doesn't show the problem!**)